# Is it possible to have a form completed with the click of an image and the image name is inserted to the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I would like to find out if an image or images could be used to completed form.

If img name = image1, then when clicking on the image/s it should add the image name to a form input field.

The form should have the selected image/s names in the input field.

Eg: if image1 is selected, the value should be image1

This is what I have done so far. I can make it change a para tag but not a form text input...

HTML

```
<p>Select the images for your music choice</p>
<img src="Images/hiphop.png" onclick="musicTaste('Hiphop')"/>

<form method="POST" action="musictaste.php">
  <input type="text" name="musicTasteSelection" id="genre">   
  Confirm your music taste: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="">
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>

  function musicTaste(genre) {
    document.getElementById('genre').innerHTML = genre;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Sure. It's pretty easy. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials about event handling (click) that would be a good place to start since it seems you don't have a _specific_ question, and there are many [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792414)s about it on Stackoverflow you could read.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have added the code i did it with one and i would duplicate it for the rest. 
i cannot make it complete the form input

Comment: Use `<label><checkbox><img/></label>` so when clicking on image it would select checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js code, you should be doing this:

```
document.getElementById('genre').value = genre;
```

To add multiple images to the input box, do this instead:

```
document.getElementById('genre').value += genre + ", ";
```

Comment: When i change the code it does nothing, what do i need to do in order for the form text box to be populated by the image name if i click on it

Comment: Ohk, please add the line ``console.log(genre);`` after the above statement, and then please tell if the console is showing any errors and what it is logging.

Comment: Works now after redoing the script works fine, is there a way to add multiple ?
for eg, if you like pop, rock, house music to add all of those to the same text field ?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can have it comma separated. For it, you'll have to make specific onclicks for each of the images passing an appropriate parameter just as you have done for the hiphop image. I've edited my post to include how to do this.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Please upvote and mark as accepted (click the tick) to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`input` elements don't have an [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property (that property is for non-form field elements that have an opening and closing tag). Form field elements have a `.value` property.

```html
<p>Select the images for your music choice</p>
<img src="Images/hiphop.png" id="pic" onclick="musicTaste('Hiphop')"/>

<form method="POST" action="musictaste.php">
  <input type="text" name="musicTasteSelection" id="genre">   
  Confirm your music taste: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="">
</form>
JS

<script>

  function musicTaste(genre) {
    document.getElementById('genre').value = genre;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Umm, that's literally what I have answered below too.

Comment: @tanmay_garg No, it's not. You didn't explain why `.innerHTML` didn't work and why `value` is needed. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not just for the OP to get their question answered, but also for future readers with the same question. Answers should strive to *explain the problem and the answer*, rather than just provide the answer, so that others can learn.